# 2 Trigger en uno SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

He creado 2 Triggers que se desencadenan por el mismo motivo y actualizan la misma base de datos, cada uno actualiza un campo distinto.

Como no se juntarlos he creado 2, se podria hacer uno junto que actualize los 2 campos?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR1] 
ON [dbo].[Datos]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
Begin
 update Usuarios 
 set Poblacion = (Select Poblacion from inserted)
 where DNI = (Select DNI from inserted)
End
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR2] 
ON [dbo].[Datos]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
Begin
 update Usuarios 
 set Telefono = (Select Telefono from inserted)
 where DNI = (Select DNI from inserted)
End
```

Comment: la documentacion de update te hubiera ayudado... update tabla set campo = valor, campo = valor where... etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay un par de problemas con el diseño. En primer lugar, estarás tratando de actualizar la misma fila dos veces. En segundo lugar, tus trigger no están diseñados para manejar múltiples filas a la vez.

Lo ideal es corregir el `UPDATE` para manejar ambas columnas y múltiples filas. El código sería similar a esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR1] 
ON [dbo].[Datos]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE u SET 
    Poblacion = i.Poblacion,
    Telefono  = i.Telefono
 FROM Usuarios u
 JOIN inserted i ON u.DNI = i.DNI;
END
```

Comment: Lo he probado tal como dices y va perfecto.  Estudiaré el contenido para aprender su funcionamiento.  Muchas gracias